# One-to-One relationship in EF Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am creating a standard example model User -> UserProfile.

ApplicationUser

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Profile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Profile

```cs
public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    public List<Bage> Bages { get; set; } = new List<Bage>();
}
```

DbContext

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bage> Bages { get; set; }
    
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is how I add data:

```
ApplicationUser botva = new ApplicationUser
{
    UserName = "12313dsafdsd2",
    Email = "dasd@gmail.com",
    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};
_context.Users.Add(botva);

Profile BotvaProfile = new Profile { Name = "123 123", AvatarUrl = "123", ApplicationUser = botva };
_context.Profiles.Add(BotvaProfile);

Bage bage = new Bage { Name = "123", ImgUrl = "url/123" };
_context.Bages.Add(bage);

BotvaProfile.Bages.Add(bage);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Everything created correctly in the database. The only problem is that the main `ApplicationUser` class, for some reason, does not contain a reference to Profile:

[image]

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is not in One-to-One relation. I think that you are getting data from DB without including Profile. 
You can read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/ to understand how to include Profile when getting ApplicationUser.

Comment: Could you show  Bage class pls?

Comment: @Sergey
`public class Bage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
        public List<Profile> Users { get; set; } = new List<Profile>();
    }`

Comment: @RubenMartirosyan yes, i can do this `var users = _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserProfile);`  but how do "Users" include "Profile" by default? Without do that queries every time

Comment: I don't see   public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users{ get; set; }

Comment: @Sergey he inherit from IdentityDbContext

Comment: @ArtemiZStudio So the questiin has nothing to do with one-to-one relationship, but [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) - it applies to all type of relationships and navigation properties. And what you are asking for is automatic eager loading.  Which can be configured as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783481/how-can-i-effectively-model-translatable-properties-in-ef-core/65784206#65784206

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inverse your classes

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int ProfileId
        public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    }

public class Profile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
        public List<Bage> Bages { get; set; } = new List<Bage>();

    }
```

in this case your code will be

```
var botvaProfile = new Profile { Name = "123 123", AvatarUrl = "123"} 
var bage = new Bage { Name = "123", ImgUrl = "url/123" };
botvaProfile.Bages.Add(bage);

ApplicationUser botva = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "12313dsafdsd2",
                Email = "dasd@gmail.com",
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Profile=botvaProfile
            };
 _context.Users.Add(botva);
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yea, reverse class structure will help, but i whant "2-side" solution